# month and year string value compared to date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

have 2 columns in table

```
id  CLOSED_DATE
1   11/01/2017
2   12/01/2017
3   12/02/2017
4   01/01/2018
5   02/01/2018
```

I have a string value of month and year in format "DEC-2017", how do i find which all is in previous months (Id: 1) and in Next months (id:4,5)

i tried like below, but it gave me id 3,4 and 5, because TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-yyyy') converted to 01-DEC-2017.

```
select id from table where TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-yyyy') > CLOSED_DATE;
```

Comment: So, you want everything in `Nov-2017`, `Jan-2018` and `Feb-2018`, but ***nothing*** from `Oct-2017`, `Dec-2017` or `Mar-2018`?

Comment: Yeah.. all previous and all future months, excluding the one i send in the query

Comment: So,  ***not*** what I said then!?  :-/

Comment: You should not rely on session settings to be as desired when dealing with names. This is an English month name so tell `TO_DATE` so in order to make this safe: TO_DATE('DEC-2017', 'MON-yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = English')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do what Gordon Said, but Modify the Conditions Slightly**

let us create a sample table, smple_t:

```
    SCOTT@db>CREATE TABLE smple_t
      2      AS
      3          SELECT
      4              ROWNUM id,
      5              ( trunc(SYSDATE) + power(-1,mod(t.rndm,2) ) * t.rndm ) closed_date
      6          FROM
      7              (
      8                  SELECT
      9                      ROWNUM id,
     10                      round(dbms_random.value *-30,0) rndm
     11                  FROM
     12                      dual
     13                  CONNECT BY
     14                      level <= 400
     15              ) t;

Table SMPLE_T created.
```

Let us check record count:

```
SCOTT@db>SELECT
  2      COUNT(1) 
  3  FROM
  4      smple_t;
  COUNT(1) 
       400
```

Now let us look at the records 1 month preceding DEC-1-2017 to 1 month after (I assume entire month of January).

The "trick" is to make sure if you want all of November that you use the `>=` operator for the lower boundary and use the `<` operator for the upper boundary:

```
SCOTT@db>SELECT
  2      COUNT(1),
  3      add_months(TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-YYYY'),-1) all_nov_dates,
  4      add_months(TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-YYYY'),2) all_jan_dates
  5  FROM
  6      smple_t
  7  WHERE
  8      1 = 1
  9      AND   closed_date < add_months(TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-YYYY'),2)
 10      AND   closed_date >= add_months(TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-YYYY'),-1)
 11  GROUP BY
 12      add_months(TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-YYYY'),-1),
 13      add_months(TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-YYYY'),2);
  COUNT(1) ALL_NOV_DATES             ALL_JAN_DATES             
---------------------------------------------------
       207 01-NOV-2017 12:00:00 AM   01-FEB-2018 12:00:00 AM
```

---

**Addendum based on update to requirement:**

OP indicated that the desired result set is non-December 2017 (or 2016) closed dates.

OP indicated, "It should give me all months id before Dec-2016 excluding Dec-2016.... Nov-16, Oct-16.. and another one result with all future months excluding Dec-2016, i.e., Jan-17,Feb-17"

When we have a disjoint result set needed (in this case with the `closed_date`), we can use the `or` operator to to achieve this

It is important to enclose the the conditions around `closed_date` in parenthesis because `AND` has operator precedence.

```
SCOTT@db>with  smple_t as
  2  (        select sysdate - 90 closed_date
  3            from dual
  4           union all
  5          select sysdate - 35 closed_date
  6            from dual
  7           union all
  8          select sysdate + 40 closed_date 
  9          from dual
 10          union all
 11          SELECT SYSDATE - 40 closed_date 
 12          from dual
 13          UNION ALL 
 14          SELECT SYSDATE + 90 closed_date
 15          FROM dual
 16  )
 17  SELECT
 18      closed_date
 19  FROM
 20      smple_t
 21  WHERE
 22      1 = 1
 23      AND   (
 24          closed_date >= add_months(TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-YYYY'),1)
 25          OR    closed_date < TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-YYYY')
 26      );
CLOSED_DATE               
-----------------------
04-NOV-2017 03:28:17 PM   
14-MAR-2018 03:28:17 PM   
03-MAY-2018 03:28:17 PM
```

Comment: `SELECT CLOSED_DATE FROM TABLE WHERE CLOSED_DATE <= ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('DEC-2016','MON-YYYY'),2);select CLOSED_DATE from TABLE where CLOSED_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('DEC-2016','MON-YYYY'),-1);` This is what i tried. My table have now, Nov-16,Dec-16, Jan-17,Feb-17,May-17. First query gave me everything except Feb and may 17 data. Second one gave me everything. Let me say what i need, for Dec-2016, it should give me all months id before Dec-2016 excluding Dec-2016.... Nov-16, Oct-16.. and another one result with all future months excluding Dec-2016, i.e., Jan-17,Feb-17...

Comment: @Pat I updated the results to reflect the disjoint set requirement.

Comment: Perfect, it worked. `closed_date < TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-YYYY')` this is the trick.TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-YYYY') equals to 01-Dec-2017 and "<" will be always previous months. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just throw in an `add_months()`:

```
select id
from table
where add_months(TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-yyyy'), 1) >= CLOSED_DATE;
```

Comment: `add_months(TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-yyyy'), 1) <= CLOSED_DATE` gives me future months. but other way around did not give me previous months, what i am missing `add_months(TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-yyyy'), 1) >= CLOSED_DATE`

Comment: @Pat you can pass a negative value to ADD_MONTHS, for example add_months(TO_DATE('DEC-2017','MON-yyyy'), -1)  will give you Nov. 1, 2017

Answer (score 2):

You want all months except for the one given? Then convert `closed_date` and compare it with the given string.

```
select id 
from table 
where to_char(closed_date, 'MON-yyyy', 'nls_date_language=english') <> 'DEC-2017';
```

Comment: I would prefer `to_char(closed_date, 'MM-yyyy') <> '12-2017'`

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit: So would I, but OP says: "I have a string value of month and year in format 'DEC-2017'".

Comment: @ThorstenKettner to get all not equals is easy one, it works with the Gordon answer, but what i need is 2 separate results which one of all future months and one of all previous month, both should exclude the month(string)  passed.